# Ngrok 3 virtual host with wamp 3.3.1

Tags: wamp, virtualhost, ngrok

I am trying to view my local site on another terminal. However, the site does not display.

On the Ngrok terminal: `ngrok.exe http 80`

On the local server's httpd-vhosts.conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.local
  serverAlias aee9-89-85-88-146.eu.ngrok.io
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/dev/test"
  <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/dev/test/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory></VirtualHost>
```

I specify that the chrome browser displays the dns_probe_finished_nxdomain error. Besides, when I don't modify the httpd-vhosts.conf file, I do have access to localhost, phpMyAdmin, phpInfo, etc.

Thank you for you precious help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who have the same problems as me when they want to use NGrok for a Wordpress site... they can just use Local WP. A kind of Wamp, reserved exclusively for Wordpress sites.

It worked for me. And what's more, there is no need for third-party software. Local WP does both the work of wamp and Ngrok.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Change `ServerName` to `localhost` so that you can access your site from localhost.
2. Ensure you can access your site from the same computer by opening localhost in the browser.
3. Start a quick tunnel using https://pinggy.io by running the command `ssh -p 443 -R0:localhost:80 a.pinggy.io`.
4. Put the URL output from the above command on the other computer's browser and check if the site is loading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I cannot use localhost as serverAlias, this is reserved.

Comment: Then get a persistent subdomain from pinggy and use that in the serverAlias

Comment: this technique surely works with a site in html/css/php and with Symfony. I tried it on Wamp. However, this poses a lot of problems with Wordpress because it specifies the url of the site in the database. When I changed the database urls, I had other problems: HTTP/HTTPS, etc. The easiest way with Wordpress is to use Local WP, an alternative to Wamp, specially designed for wordpress